# Problema con arreglos bidimensionales

Tags: c

**Saludos, tengo un problema, cuando quiero imprimir los números que estan dentro de la matriz que está dentro del case 1, no me imprime todos los números que introduje solo los ultimos que introduje por ejemplo si introduje en una matriz 2x2 los numeros: 1, 2, 3, 4 , el programa me imprime solo 3 y 4**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {

    int  menu = 0, x = 0, y = 0, i = 0, j = 0, ac = 0, p_g = 0, arr[x][y];

    printf("   #----------------------#\n   # Temperturas y Edades # \n   #----------------------#");
    printf("\n\n1. Calcular edad de trabajadores.\n2. Calcular Temperaturas.");

    printf("\n\n- Seleccione una opcion: ");
    scanf("%i", &menu);
    system("cls");
    
    switch (menu) {

    case 1:

        printf("#----------#\n#  Edades  # \n#----------#");
        printf("\n\n- Por favor introduzca en # de filas que tendra la Matriz: ");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        printf("\n- Por favor introduzca en # de columnas que tendra la Matriz: ");
        scanf("%i", &y);

        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {

                printf ("\n\nIntroduzca la edad en la posicion (%i,%i) de la matriz: ", i,j);
                scanf("%i", &p_g);
                arr[i][j] = p_g;

            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {

                printf("[%i]",arr[i][j]);

            }
        }

        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Hola2");
        break;

    default:

        printf("- Introdujo una opcion incorrecta, porfavor intente de nuevo.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: intenta declarar tu arreglo después de pedir las filas y columnas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el código con la solución y algunos comentarios. Una variable en c no puede ser definida en cualquier parte del código, y es por ello que un arreglo no puede ser definido dentro del case 1. La solución a este problema está en encapsular el case 1, lo que significa encerrar todo el código del case 1 entre corchetes para que así el arreglo definido en el case 1 se vuelva una variable local lo que signfica que el arreglo sólo será válido en el case 1.

Esto no resulta un problema, sino que mas bien una solución necesaria ya que no es permitido declarar un arreglo sin tamaño específico, lo cual hace necesario declarar el arreglo después de solicitar su tamaño. Si la respuesta te fué útil márcala con el check.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int  menu=0, x = 0, y = 0, p_g = 0;


    printf("   #----------------------#\n   # Temperturas y Edades # \n   #----------------------#");

    printf("\n\n1. Calcular edad de trabajadores.\n2. Calcular Temperaturas.");

    printf("\n\n- Seleccione una opcion: ");
    scanf("%i", &menu);

    system("cls");


    switch (menu) {
    case 1:
        {
        //Para que la declaración del arreglo en el case 1 no te genere errores, lo que debes hacer es envolver el case 1 en un bloque explícito
        //Recuerda que si quieres usar el arreglo "int arr[x][y];" en el case 2 no podrás ya que sólo lo declarastes para el case 1
        //Si quieres usar otro arreglo en el case 2 debes declarar el arreglo en el case 2 y encerrar el case 2 en un bloque explícito {} para que
        //puedas usar ese arreglo solo en el case 2
        printf("#----------#\n#  Edades  # \n#----------#");

        printf("\n\n- Por favor introduzca en # de filas que tendra la Matriz: ");
        scanf("%i", &x);

        printf("\n- Por favor introduzca en # de columnas que tendra la Matriz: ");
        scanf("%i", &y);

        //El arreglo se define después de que le asignastes el tamaño
        int arr[x][y];

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                printf ("\n\nIntroduzca la edad en la posicion (%i,%i) de la matriz: ", i,j);
                scanf("%i", &p_g);
                arr[i][j] = p_g;
            }
        }


        printf ("\n\nEl arreglo es:\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                printf("[%i] ", arr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;

    }
    case 2:
        printf("Hola2");
        break;

    default:
        printf("- Introdujo una opcion incorrecta, porfavor intente de nuevo.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Graacias, no me había percatado de que tenia que colocar los corchetes, soy nuevo en C y lo estoy aprendiendo en la uni, poco a poco se va aprendiendo gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Anzarpe97 No hay problema. No dudes en preguntar en la comunidad cuando tengas problemas.

Comment: Otra preguntita, se que es mala practica declarar los contadores de los bucles al inicio del codigo, y tu lo hiciste bien, lo declaraste dentro el bucle pero no me compilaba tuve que quitar el "int" dentro del bucle y volverlo a colocar al inicio y asi si compiló

Comment: Que raro, porque a mi si me compilo todo bien. Lo que pasa es que no es correcto declarar los contadores al inicio, o también es cuestión de costumbre, según a como a ti te guste programar.